# Jquery type=number

Tags: jquery, input

При вводе не числа в Chrome, выдает сообщение об ошибке. В Мозиле, не выдает...и т.д.
Но хотелось бы сделать единую проверку на ввод чисел.
Код замечательно работает при input type=text:

```
$('.sq input').unbind().blur( function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var val = $(this).val();
    switch(id)
    {
        case 'id_sq_pl':
            if(!val.length) return false;
            val = +val.replace(',','.');
            if(!val) {$(this).val('');alert('Введите правильное число'); return false};
            val = Math.round( val * 10 ) / 10;
            $(this).val((''+val).replace('.',','))
        break;
    }

});
```

а вообще нужна, такая проверка:

```
$('.sq input').unbind().blur( function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var v = $(this).val();
    var r = /^[0-9]?\d{0,5}[\.,]?\d{0,1}$/g;
    switch(id)
    {
        case 'id_sq_pl':
            if (r.test(v) || v == '' ) {
                $(this).val(v);
                $(this).next().text('Правильно');
            } else {
                $(this).next().text('Не правильно');
            }
        break;
    }

});
```

но опять таки выдает, в любом случае Правильно

пс. Нужно: 
 - пустое поле // ОК
 - .5 // в 0.5 и ,5 в 0.5
 - 5. и 5, // в 5 
 - 5,555 // 5.5 (округляет)
 - иное Не правильно, т.е. все варианты человеческих ошибок при вводе

само поле input type=number

Код к комментарию **Fike**

```
$('.sq input').unbind().blur( function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var v = $(this).val();
    switch(id)
    {
        case 'id_sq_pl':
            if (parseFloat(v)) {
                //var v = parseFloat(v).toFixed(1);
                v = Math.round( v * 10 ) / 10; // этот вариант получше округляет вроде
                $(this).val(v);
                $(this).next().text('Правильно');
            } else {
                $(this).next().text('Введите число!').addClass('text-alert');
            }
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: вам поможет функция parseFloat() c последующим применением метода toFixed().
parseFloat('.55555').toFixed(2) = "0.56" (обратите внимание, что на выходе получается именно строка)

Comment: то что нужно, но пропустить пустое значение, если нажать Enter, то пустое значение формы проходит, иначе Введите число! Если скажем сделать if (parseFloat(v) || v=''), то сообщение Введите число! мы не увидим никогда, т.к. не правильные значения просто сбрасываются, что не хорошо, т.к. человек не увидит, то что это поле осталось пустым... Код выше